# Floating figure with figcaption matching image width. CSS solution that works in both Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

Basically I have a floating image, which has some arbitrary size based on the image being loaded (capped to some max-width %), with a caption below. (In the examples, I set a fixed size just for demonstration.)

Initially, I had a problem getting the figcaption to auto-fit to the size of the image above it. I used the `display: table-caption` style to get that to work in Firefox, but it breaks in Chrome.

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <img />
    <figcaption>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
}
figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45jk62s8/

In Chrome, for me, the figcaption looks all scrunched up, not the same width as the image.

If I change the figure element to `display: table`, it works in Chrome but not Firefox.

```css
figure {
  display: table;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45jk62s8/1/

In Firefox, for me, the figure is no longer horizontally centered and the figcaption width is not constrained. I tried `width: fit-content` but that doesn't work since the figcaption is allowed to run long.

I assume it has something to do with the wrapper div I use to center the figure, but I can't figure out a cross-browser solution to this at the moment. The figure does need to be fixed and centered, such that even if the behind content is scrollable, the figure is always centered in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS seems to create the desired output in Firefox and Chrome. It uses `table`, `table-cell` and `table-caption` for all the components and removes the 100% width on the caption.

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
figure {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  display: table-cell;
}
figcaption {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks! The 100% width seemed to be the main culprit, but I like using both changes as it makes most sense.